# How to replace values above 99th percentile with values at the 99th percentile?

Tags: r, regression

I have these credit quality variables (Authorized Amount, Loan term, Credit Score, LTV, etc). I have the 99th percentile of these variables and want to replace values above the 99th percentile with the value at the 99th percentile? How can I do this? I saw other examples, but couldn't quite get it right. But want to replace values above 202.33 with 202.33 and want to name it a new column so I can input it in the variables needed for regression.
Sample Data (can't show full data, but will show a few rows)

[enter image description here][1]

Below is how I got the 99th percentile.

```
quantile(mydata$RequestedLTV, probs =(.99), na.rm=TRUE)
# set values above 99th percentile with value of 99th percentile
# 202.33 is 99th percentile


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDK2v.png
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add reproducible data to your example?

Comment: You can do: `q <- quantile(mydata$RequestedLTV, .99); mydata$RequestedLTV[mydata$RequestedLTV >= q] <- q`

Comment: Sorry. Can't post pictures. Trying to link it. But this replaces all the numbers it seems; mydata$RequestedLTVCapped <- quantile(mydata$RequestedLTV, .99)

mydata$RequestedLTV[mydata$RequestedLTV >= mydata$RequestedLTVCapped] <- mydata$RequestedLTVCapped

View(mydata$RequestedLTVCapped)

Comment: mydata$RequestedLTVCapped
   [1] 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119
  [13] 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119 202.0119
  [25] 202.0119 202.0119

Comment: You should never show pictures of data.  Showing printed output of data is better (at least it can be cut and pasted), but the best is to use `dput(x)` to output code that reproduces `x`.  You can edit that into your question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It can severely distort the distribution of your data, which can lead to issues in your data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Maël's code:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = 1:1000
)
pct99 = quantile(df$x, probs = c(.99))
df[df$x > pct99, ] <- pct99

tail(df, 15)
          x
986  986.00
987  987.00
988  988.00
989  989.00
990  990.00
991  990.01
992  990.01
993  990.01
994  990.01
995  990.01
996  990.01
997  990.01
998  990.01
999  990.01
1000 990.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Also called clipping

```
pmin(mtcars$mpg,quantile(mtcars$mpg,0.99))
```

you can save the output in a new column.